# Run animation again on hover

Tags: animation, svg, hover

I created an anim https://designordering.com/resume/. I would like to run the animation again on hover.

```css
.circle1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 345;
  stroke-dashoffset: 320;
  animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 157.5;
  }
}


/*I was trying this doesn't work*/

:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-skills">
  <div class="app-circle">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="app-logos" src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/Adobe-Illustrator.png" alt="js logo" width="35px">
      </div>
    </div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100px" height="100px">
      <circle class="circle1" cx="45" cy="45" r="40"
        stroke-linecap="round" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="app-name">
    <p>Adobe<br> Illustrator</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me with advices? thank you so much!

The animation starts when the page is loaded but I would like to run it again when someone hover over the circle. It is important to run twice (or as much time someone hover over it). Thank you so much again in advence to your advices.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, I have 12 circles to apply this animation I am trying to find a way how to fix that as you can see here https://designordering.com/resume/ I have whole other issues with this page, right now I want to fix these icons

Answer (score 0):

I see you've discovered one of the most annoying flaws in the SVG standard: the lack of an easy way to restart animations! Luckily, you only have 1 element to restart.

First: don't use "fill: none;" use "transparent" instead. When you use "none", the hit area will be the width of the stroke only -- not the entire inside of the circle! I'm pretty sure you do not want someone having to precisely hover over the stroke itself.

On hover, use a second keyframe, like this:

```
circle:hover{
    animation: anim2 2s 1 linear forwards;
}
```

You need the whole animation declaration. Can't just do "animation-name"

Here's my whole fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zombiedoctor/y0qwbu84/

Comment: don't ever use transparent, use the pointer-events property instead.

Comment: thanks for the pointer-events tip. I see that "transparent" is not strictly valid but filling it with any color and setting fill-opacity to 0 would also do the trick.

Comment: using pointer-events is even better than that.